# Compiling with /EHa: any problems with 3rd party .lib/.dll?

Tags: visual-c++, exception, compilation

I'm considering using the /EHa compiler switch when building in Debug and Release.  I'm using a bunch of 3rd party static libraries and DLLs, which I'm assuming didn't get compiled with /EHa.  Will I be running into any problems?

Comment: If it makes a difference, I will be using _set_se_translator to convert the structural exceptions into C++ exceptions.

Comment: I made the changes and no problems so far.  If all stay good I will answer "no" to this question in the near future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been compiling and handling errors for the past week or so, and no problems since the change yet.